# Case with NULL expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, expression, case, coalesce, nullif

I have a problem with this piece of code and i'm pretty sure the solution is quite easy, but i don't see it.

```
CASE @L0 WHEN '/' THEN NULL ELSE @L0 END
```

It is part of code i use to import data out of a flat file (csv), where NULL is stored as /. The problem is that @L0 can also be an input variable filled by another programm and it is possible that it might be NULL. Due to that it's not allowed to use a NULL value as expression in a CASE, the code doesn't work and i get an error message.

Can somebody tell me how to do it the right way?

Comment: So what should the result be if `@L0` is `NULL`?

Comment: CASE ISNULL(@L0, '/')
 WHEN '/' THEN NULL 
END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would just like to replace the `'/'` with `NULL` and leave all other strings untouched, you can use the `NULLIF()` function e.g. `NULLIF(@Lo, '/')`

Comment: i already tried NULLIF and COALESCE, but it's the same problem: the expression is not allowed to be NULL

Comment: The expression is only not allowed to be a `NULL` constant. So only if you (or your SQL code generation) write literally `NULLIF(NULL, '/')` you will get the error. This is because SQL Server cannot determine the type of the return value if you pass `NULL` as a constant.

Comment: exactly. But how to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand. What is there to fix. Can't you just **not** pass a `NULL` constant? Is it because you generate the SQL string? If so, you can just cast the value e.g. `NULLIF(cast(NULL as <someDataType>), '/')` where `<someDataType>`should be the data type of your input. But as I understand your example, you are not passing `NULL` as a **constant** but as the value of your `@LO` variable in which case there is no problem.

Comment: Almost fixed my problem...this here did the trick: CAST(NULLIF(@L0, '/') AS NUMERIC(18)) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Map a NULL value to '/' or any other string:

```
 CASE COALESCE(@L0, '/') WHEN '/' THEN NULL ELSE @L0 END

 CASE COALESCE(@L0, 'other string') WHEN '/' THEN NULL ELSE COALESCE(@L0, 'other string') END
```

The 'other string' should of course never occur as regular non-null content of @L0. In case the result should be '/' on @L0 being the 'other string', take this one:

```
 CASE COALESCE(@L0, 'other string') WHEN '/' THEN NULL ELSE COALESCE(@L0, '/') END
```

Comment: That doesn't work, too. If @L0 is NULL, then the expression is also NULL again. CASE COALESCE(null, '/') WHEN '/' THEN NULL ELSE null END

Comment: As i need to inlcude the command in an insert statement, i can't use your proposal in that way. Anyway, Christian's answer brought me on the right track, i was able to fix my problem with his (and also the help of you other guys) answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, which defaults `@L0` to '/' if it is null:

```
CASE COALESCE(@L0, '/') WHEN '/' THEN NULL ELSE @L0 END
```